# Use different domaine for Admin and Front

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api

How can we use different domaine for the Front and the admin section. If I'm changing the domaine on the base URL of the store config, I'm getting a 404 because there's no admin on this domaine.

I've build a PWA on a different domaine `www.mydomaine.com` and the backend is on `api.mydomaine.com`.